# SELINUX won't enable

Tags: fedora, selinux

I just checked to see if SELINUX was enabled on my server like this

```
[root@fedora ~]# getenforce
Disabled
```

However, when I look at the `/etc/selinux/config` file I see this

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=enforcing
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these three values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are pr$
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

How do I making it so SELINUX actually sets to enforcing? Preferably without rebooting the server.

When I run `[root@fedora ~]# setenforce 1` I get this message

```
setenforce: SELinux is disabled
```

And SELINUX remains disabled.

Comment: `setenforce [0|1]` toggles between permissive and enforcing; it cannot *enable* SELinux on a running system.

Comment: Ah, ok. But with the above config file in place it should enable after I reboot, right?

Comment: I would expect it to be enabled after a boot with the given `/etc/selinux/config`.  If it is not, we need more information.  (Was the file already in that state last time the system was booted?  I think recent Fedora all have SELinux enabled by default.)   Check https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/11/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-Enabling_and_Disabling_SELinux.html

Comment: It was a clean install of Fedora on a Linode using the default settings. I assume the conf file was that way when it was installed as I haven't changed it since. Either way I'll reboot and see if it helps.

Comment: Rebooted the server using `shutdown -r now`. Same issue on reboot. Any more info you need?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user is on linode with a linode provided (custom) kernel that doesn't support SELinux.

Comment: It's up to you guys if you want to close it or not, really, but I'll attempt to implement Stephen's solution tomorrow, so perhaps the question might be useful to others? Either way this has been very useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking with the Linode people it seems the version of Fedora 24 installed by default on Linodes has a custom kernel that doesn't support SELinux and that's why it's not working. So the only solution would be to reimage the whole thing, which is a little drastic, so I'm just going to do without it.

Comment: If you're using a KVM instance (if not, migrate from the linode control panel) then you can switch to using the Fedora native kernel; eg https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/custom-kernels-distros/run-a-distributionsupplied-kernel-with-pvgrub - I do this with CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

To enable SELinux without rebooting use `setenforce 1`.
Note that if SELinux has been disabled for some time you will need to `restorecon` files without or with incorrect labels.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work :/. Added step to answer.