# SELinux Doesn't Switch to "Enforcing" Mode

Tags: centos, selinux

I have a minimal CentOS 7.5.1804 (Core) system and trying to change SELinux mode from *Disabled* to *Enforcing* but when I tried to change mode using `setenforce 1` command, I got an error message says:
`setenforce: SELINUX is disabled`

I changed */etc/selinux/config* file as follows:

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.`
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:`
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=enforcing
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these three values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are pr$
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

I rebooted system a couple of times but still SELinux is disabled.

Where am I suppose to check now? Is there any other mechanism above */etc/selinux/config* file that can manipulate SELinux status?

*Note 1* : I didn't install and configure CentOS 7 on the machine at first hand. So, certain customization might have been done after the installation. System currently has three SELinux policy packages as follows:

```
selinux-policy-minimum
selinux-policy-mls
selinux-policy-targeted
```

*Note 2* : This question is similar with [SELINUX won't enable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303834/selinux-wont-enable) and i know it has closed with an *off-topic* flag. But it closed because *the user is on linode with a linode provided (custom) kernel that doesn't support SELinux* (as Stephen Harris says in comments)

Comment: cat /proc/cmdline there is probably selinux=0 enforcing=0. if so - change your grub configuration.

Comment: some [RHEL](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-working_with_selinux-changing_selinux_modes) [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-enabling_and_disabling_selinux-dracut-parameters). Note the required packages in chapter 4.3. look for Alexander's provided offending toggles in /etc/default/grub (+ man grub2-mkconfig)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some researches considering comments of [Alexander](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/304809/alexander) and [A.B](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/251756/a-b). Solution steps that I implemented as follows:

1. In `/etc/grub.d/` directory, a file called `40_custom` contains an expression as `selinux=0` (btw I was seeing the same expression at *grub bootloader menu*). I changed it to `selinux=1`.
2. Executing command`grub2-mkconfig -0 /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`. Executing ends successfully.
3. I checked once again if `/etc/selinux/config` file has the `SELINUX=enforcing` expression.

After a reboot, SELinux `getenforce` command shows `Enforcing`.