# SELinux won't enable on AlmaLinux

Tags: linux, selinux, alma-linux

I can't enable SELinux on a fresh image install of AlmaLinux 8.7.

After reboot:

```
[root@cs46949 stdusr]# cat /etc/redhat-release &&
> uptime &&
> dnf -y install policycoreutils selinux-policy selinux-policy-targeted libselinux-utils setroubleshoot-server setools setools-console &&
> dnf update &&
> cat /etc/selinux/config &&
> sestatus
AlmaLinux release 8.7 (Stone Smilodon)
 10:03:08 up 0 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.27, 0.08, 0.03
Last metadata expiration check: 0:18:10 ago on Sat Dec 24 09:46:52 2022.
Package policycoreutils-2.9-20.el8.x86_64 is already installed.
Package selinux-policy-3.14.3-108.el8.noarch is already installed.
Package selinux-policy-targeted-3.14.3-108.el8.noarch is already installed.
Package libselinux-utils-2.9-6.el8.x86_64 is already installed.
Package setroubleshoot-server-3.3.26-5.el8.x86_64 is already installed.
Package setools-4.3.0-3.el8.x86_64 is already installed.
Package setools-console-4.3.0-3.el8.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
Last metadata expiration check: 0:18:12 ago on Sat Dec 24 09:46:52 2022.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=enforcing
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these three values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected.
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted


SELinux status:                 disabled
```

Remark: This is the same question as [SELINUX won't enable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/303834/189709) , but that one is closed and off topic (because the user is on linode with a linode provided (custom) kernel that doesn't support SELinux). AlmaLinux has a RHEL binary compatible kernel vers. 4.18.0

Comment: Did you place the line `SELinux status:                 disabled` in the file? Have you tried removing it and then rebooting? Does `setenforce 0` and then `getenforce` return `enforcing`?

Comment: @NasirRiley No, 'SELinux status: disabled' is the output of the last command 'sestatus'. System is fresh rebooted (see uptime: 0 minutes). 'setenforce 0' output is 'setenforce: SELinux is disabled'. 'getenforce' returns 'disabled'.

Comment: My mistake. If you run `setenforce 1` and then `getenforce`, does that return `enforcing`?

Comment: @NasirRiley both commands return that SELinux is disabled. To enable SELinux, one has to enter the settings I put in the /etc/selinux/config file and reboot. But that doesn't work here and that's why I've posted my question.

Comment: That isn't the case in Alma Linux or nearly all Linux distributions. In the case of Alma, I've been using it since it was released and like other distros, SELinux can be enabled and disabled with the `setenforce command. The config change in `/etc/selinux/config` is only to get it to persist across reboots. If you get an ISO from one of the actual mirrors and install it into a VM instead of using a doctored version that's going to have different settings, then you'll see that `setenforce` works to enable and disable it immediately and that you can set it in the file to persist at boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This AlmaLinux instance is provided by dogado.de and runs as a VM under Paralles Virtuozzo. Accorrding to their documentation, it doesn't support SELinux.